# Spring Cloud with multiple UI services as one

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

Is it possible to use spring cloud for creating a integration between multiple web ui applications as one using a common service that can integrate all URLs in menus to presented as one application?

In addition, based on previous description, how can is it possible distribute this application in multiples servers and reference them using eureka and securing it with zuul services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if I read correctly, you are describing microservice architecture. You need to read up on this. There is no "right" or "wrong" way to do this; it is highly dependent upon your situation. The first link references all of the technologies you are interested in.

- http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2015/04/10/building-microservices-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-oss-part-1/
- https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring
- http://microservices.io/

Comment: Yes, Its exactly what I'm looking for. In addition, I found a sample at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js that explains each part of architecture, however, I'm still concerned about the number of ports that have to be set for each service in order to manage the infraestructure.